# I keep getting an ImportError despite being my module being in the cwd

Tags: python, python-3.x

Structure:

```
scrapy_test_project
        scrapy_test_project
               __init__.py
               items.py
               main.py
               spiders
                   quote_spider.py
```

quote_spider.py contains a class and items.py contains a class.

When I attempt to import items.py from my quote_spider.py file it appears to be recognized by VSCODE but I keep getting an import error. I'm completely stuck.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File
> "c:\Users\Denze\Projects\testing\scrapy_test_project\scrapy_test_project\spiders\quotes_spider.py",
> line 7, in module
> from items import TestItem 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'items'

Import code:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append('scrapy_test_project/scrapy_test_project')
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from items import TestItem
```

my cwd: C:\Users\Denze\Projects\testing\scrapy_test_project\scrapy_test_project

Answer (score 0):

So, as long, as your file is in `scrapy_test_project` module, you can just do

```
import sys
import os
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy_test_project.items import TestItem
```

Comment: See that's what I thought but I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy_test_project' error

Comment: try creating __init__.py file in spiders folder

Comment: I already have a init.py file in my spiders folder so that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I guess your `__init__.py` is empty then, insert `from .items import TestItem` into your main `__init__.py` and then try answer above. Hope it helps)

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with VSCode not recognizing something installed on PATH. (Make sure it is). Try starting VSCode as admin, right-click, Run As administrator. Every time I have used the CMD and pip to install a new python package I noticed VS wouldn't recognize it. Also, as far as Python is concerned, make sure in the bottom left corner you select the correct interpreter path.